# Retrofit Throwing null pointer exception

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

## Showing Null pointer exception** in this code.

** yrWebService.getUserInfo()**

I have tried most of the things but I can't figure it out.
Anyone please help to fix this issue.
The getUserInfo() throwing null pointer exception.
someone help me to solve this. I pasted the interface down there.

```
    public  void fetchUserProfile() {
    YRWebService.getUserInfo()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<YRUserResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Toast.makeText(YarraApplication.this, "Error on server :" +e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(YRUserResponse yrUserResponse) {
                    //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (yrUserResponse != null) {
                        if (yrUserResponse.getUser() != null) {
                            YRPreferenceManager.setString(PreferenceKeys.USER_PROFILE_RESPONSE,
                                    new Gson().toJson(yrUserResponse));
                            YRUser  yrUser = yrUserResponse.getUser();
                            YarraApplication.userId = yrUserResponse.getUser().getUser_id();
                            YarraApplication.access = yrUserResponse.getUser().getGoogle_access_token();
                            YarraApplication.email = yrUser.getEmail();
                            YarraApplication.fName = yrUser.getFirst_name();
                            YarraApplication.lName = yrUser.getLast_name();
                            YarraApplication.mobile = yrUser.getTelephone();


                        }else {
                         // YRUtils.showUnknownErrorDialog(YarraApplication.this);
                        }
                    }// else {
                    // YRUtils.showUnknownErrorDialog(UserProfileActivity.this);
                    // }
                }
            });
}


**Interface :::: **
```

The interface we are using here is this

```
public interface YRWebService {
 @GET("/users")
    Observable<YRUserResponse> getUserInfo();
}

public class YRUserResponse  {

    List<YRError> errors;

    YRUser user;

    public YRUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(YRUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

````
 
 
 **retrofit.RetrofitError**:
 
 ```


   2019-05-06 15:26:49.506 30475-30475/com.rever.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.rever.app, PID: 30475
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rever.app/com.rever.app.UserProfileActivity}: retrofit.RetrofitError
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
          Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError
             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
             at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
             at $Proxy0.getUserInfo(Unknown Source)
             at com.rever.app.UserProfileActivity.fetchUserProfile(UserProfileActivity.java:220)
             at com.rever.app.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:132)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
          Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
             at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
             at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:29)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:231)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:317)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:198)
             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
             at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913) 
             at $Proxy0.getUserInfo(Unknown Source) 
             at com.rever.app.UserProfileActivity.fetchUserProfile(UserProfileActivity.java:220) 
             at com.rever.app.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:132) 
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084) 
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075) 
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
     ```
````

Comment: The exception you've put in the question is because you're doing a network request in the main thread. Looking at the Rx chain you have it's hard to see how this can be thrown in `fetchUserProfile`. Could you post the code for all of these methods? The schedulers look fine. The problem should be somewhere else